# WinService: создание горячих клавиш для запуска приложений

Tags: c#, windows-service, hotkeys

Пишу сервис, который будет запускать или закрывать мои приложения через горячие клавиши(например с помощью клавиш CTRL + ALT + a + 1 запускается приложение(если оно не запущено)).

Поискал в инете информацию, но что-то похожее для сервиса нечего не нашел. Как это реализовать? Прошу Вашей помощи.

Comment: Насколько я знаю, сервис не имеет возможности перехватывать события клавиатуры. Взамен можете сделать десктопное приложение со скрытым окном. Ну а дальше - [хуки](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/toub/2006/05/03/low-level-keyboard-hook-in-c/)

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Благодарю! Снова выручили)